# Converting native buffer wrappers to C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am trying to port a native C++ library to C++/CLI, so I can use it in C#. I am trying to figure out how to convert a few of the classes that basically lightly wrap a buffer for extracting fields. I've written a small sample to better describe what is going on in the API.

So, I have a `Packet` class that reads packets from a file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include "OptionalA.h"

class Packet
{
public:
    Packet(void)
    {
        buffer = new char[PACKET_SIZE];
    }
    ~Packet(void)
    {
        delete [] buffer;
    }

    void ReadNextPacket(std::ifstream& fileStream)
    {
        fileStream.read(buffer, PACKET_SIZE);
    }

    bool HasOptionalA()
    {
        return (buffer[0] & 0x1) == 1;
    }

    OptionalA GetOptionalA()
    {
        assert(HasOptionalA());
        return OptionalA(&buffer[1], &buffer[1] + OptionalA::OPTIONAL_A_SIZE);
    }

private:
    const static int PACKET_SIZE = 3;
    char* buffer;
};
```

The `Packet` I created has a very simple format:

`[Packet: <Header Byte> [OptionalA: <Field1><Field2>]]`

The `OptionalA` class is defined as follows:

```
#pragma once
#include <cassert>

class OptionalA
{
public:
    static const int OPTIONAL_A_SIZE = 2;

    OptionalA(const char* begin = 0, const char* end = 0) :
    begin(begin), end(end)
    {
        assert((end - begin) == OPTIONAL_A_SIZE);
    }

    char GetField1()
    {
        return begin[0];
    }

    char GetField2()
    {
        return begin[1];
    }

private:
    const char* begin;
    const char* end;
};
```

What is the correct way to wrap this type of class architecture such that I duplicate the minimum amount of memory in C++/CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple way, but somewhat time consuming depending on the amount of classes you have to convert, is to create CLI wrappers that contain a native pointer to the type they wrap:

```
ref class FileStream
{
public:
  FileStream( String^ file ) :
    p( new std::ifstream() )
  {
    //open the stream here, if it fails throw a managed exception that makes sense
  }

    //bonus: CLI classes automatically implement IDisposable so 
    //this gets called at the end of scope with 'using( var x = new FileStream(){}'
  ~FileStream()
  {
    delete p;
  }

    //make sure to implement a finalizer to make the GC work with this class
  !FileStream()
  {
    this->~FileStream();
  }

  //not repeating all functions here, we just use this as a placeholder
  std::ifstream& Stream()
  {
    return *p;
  }

private: 
  std::ifstream* p;
}

ref class Packet
{
public:
  Packet() :
    p( new native::Packet() )
  {
  }

  //again destructor/finalizer pair

  void ReadNextPacket( FileStream^ fileStream )
  {                   
    if( fileStream == nullptr )
      throw gcnew System::ArgumentNullException( "fileStream" );
    p->ReadNextPacket( fileStream->Stream() );
  }                   

  bool HasOptionalA()
  {
    return p->HasOptionalA();
  }

  OptionalA^ GetOptionalA()
  {
    retrun gcnew OptionalA( p->GetOptionalA() );
  }

private:
  native::Packet* p;
};

ref class OptionalA
{
public:
  OptionalA( const native::OptionalA& optionalA ) :
    p( new native::OptionalA( optionalA ) )
  {
  }

  //again destructor/finalizer pair

  char GetField1()    
  {    
    return p=>GetField1();   
  }    

private:
  native::OptionalA* p;
}
```

To spice things up and make better code, consider using something [like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object) instead of raw native pointers and get cleanup for free. Also maybe consider using std::string and passing iterators around instead of raw char pointers, it's C++ after all.

Comment: I was going to recommend my smart pointer, then I saw you already did.  Great choice!  But please note that your code fails to implement a finalizer, and your comment that the destructor gets called automatically by the GC is wrong, it will leak if not explicitly disposed.  It's somewhat tricky to get right, so use the smart pointer ;)

Comment: Also, I assume you intended to make `FileStream::Stream` a property?  The syntax is wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for pointing out those issues, I wrote everything from scratch so was bound to make some mistakes :] fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought about using the default copy constructor to take advantage of `const` pointers. That's a clever idea :)